# Github Action: "workflow_dispatch" How to always use the master branch (remove option to change branch)

Tags: github-actions

In Github actions, I've included a `workflow_dispatch:` trigger in my yaml to allow me to trigger the action on demand. The master branch must always be triggered, and I've configured the action to always checkout from master- BUT the workflow gui trigger always asks for a branch. I'd like to make this dropdown hidden (or unchangeable) if possible

Here is my settings for the `workflow_dispatch` trigger

```yaml
name: 'MIGRATE DATABASE TEST'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'target environment'
        required: true
        default: 'qa'
        type: choice
        options:
          - stage
          - qa

jobs:
  ...........
```

As you can see, the "Use workflow from" option is shown, but I don't need it because I always want to trigger this from master.
**Question: How can I force it to ALWAYS user master, AND to never show this unneeded dropdown.**
[image: force workflow to always use master, then never show this option]

Comment: If you always checkout the master then it doesn't matter which branch is selected. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but if possible it would be nice to get rid of a useless drop-down to make it easier to understand for people who come after me

Comment: Then I guess you should create an enhancement request to GitHub.

Comment: This dropdown does not make sense at all. Anyone can write any workflow in a branch and trigger this. GitHub should get rid of this.

Comment: There should be a way to stop this. This allows folks to run the workflow of their choice on production

Comment: @everythingEzra2 Did anything ever come of this? It's totally something Github needs to at least allow people to override (to not show).

Comment: @mellis481 I've never found a way to do it- we just make sure to always run it with the default matter branch selected :(

Answer (score 1):

You can fail the workflow if it's not done on the correct branch

```
name: Deploy web prod

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - prod

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # fails the workflow dispatch if not on the right branch
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/prod'
    steps:
```

Answer (score -4):

`workflow_dispatch` always shows the branch from which you need to run the workflow against. This is the default behavior.

If you would like your workflow to run against a `push` to master, you can use the push event

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'
```

Above will always run the workflow automatically on push events to main. *You can find other events that trigger workflows from the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows).*

Now you will have to find other ways to pass your environment input.

1. Creating a composite action having a `environment` input with default value `qa`
2. [Using configuration variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-configuration-variables-for-multiple-workflows)